# HTML Email - How do you remove -webkit-margin-before: 1em; -webkit-margin-after: 1em; which is automatically added to <p> in outlook.com (hotmail)?

Tags: html, html-email, hotmail, outlook.com

I have tried adding the following as an inline style on my `<p>` but outlook.com/hotmail.com strips it out and adds 1em margin to before and after `<p>`.

```css
margin-before:0!important;
 -webkit-margin-before:0!important;
 margin-after:0!important;
 -webkit-margin-after:0!important
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the easiest solution is to not use a `p` tag. Just place your copy inside a `td` and apply all inline styling as normal. Gives you more control over the content and saves you battling against default added styles from clients/browsers

Comment: Thank you. This is probably a more sound and permanent solution than the using style="Margin: 0!important; Padding: 0!important;"

Comment: I agree: first choice is not to use `<p>` tags, but if you can't avoid it (eg. your importing markup that you can't alter) capitalizing the 'M' should scale just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<p style="Margin-top:0;Margin-bottom:0;"></p>
```

For some unknown reason Outlook.com strips margins unless you use a capital M.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I set my paragraphs to Padding: 0!important; Margin:0!important

Answer (score 0):

Just override them by adding `margin: 0;` to `<p>`
You can probably add `!important` to the `margin`.

Comment: That doesn't work. Outlook strips out margin and then adds: 
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}

Comment: Did you try these: `<p style="margin: 0 !important;"></p>`? Adding a style that will override the `margin`?

Comment: Yes. I tried: 

<p style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica,Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:300; font-size:18px; line-height:26px; padding: 0 0 0 0!important; margin: 0!important; -webkit-margin-before: 0!important; -webkit-margin-after: 0!important; margin-before: 0!important; margin-after: 0!important">

Comment: @ynot
Can you post your full code so I can look up to it?

Comment: You want the `margin` stuff to be 0 right? I quite find the issue here that gives a gap between `<p>` 's. Try removing the `<br>` between them and you can get your desired output.

Comment: Like I said in the beginning, outlook.com ads p { display: block; -webkit-margin-before: 1em; -webkit-margin-after: 1em; -webkit-margin-start: 0px; -webkit-margin-end: 0px; }. I'm not trying to remove the space, the problem is that there's too much space when you view it on outlook.

Comment: Of course there is too much space, when you put BR elements between the paragraphs ... what are those doing there in the first place? Per default paragraphs have spacing between them already (via the default margins), so what are those BR _doing_ there?

Comment: @CBroe I'm trying to find a method where I don't have to be at the mercy of styles forced on me by mail clients. This is why I first set all margins and padding to 0 and then use the br for spacing because br is uniform across clients.